# CARingBuffer replacement for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-audio

What might be good *Swift* replacement for *C++* class CARingBuffer in audio application which uses just following API:

```cpp
CARingBuffer *mBuffer = new CARingBuffer()
mBuffer->Allocate(...)
mBuffer->Store(...)
mBuffer->Fetch(...)
mBuffer->GetTimeBounds(...)
```

Thank you!

**Update**: Interested in pure Swift implementation (without C/C++ bridging).

**Udpate 2**: Swift implementation allowed to use low-level C API, such as `memcpy`, `OSAtomicCompareAndSwapLongBarrier`, etc.

**Update 3**: Lets assume that linker issues addressed to `Whole Module Optimization` are temporary and will be solved in newer version of `swift` toolchain.

**Update 4**: After implementing [CARingBuffer in Swift](https://github.com/vgorloff/CARingBuffer) and running performance tests (C++ and Swift) I got some numbers:

2 000 000 cycles (2 channels, 44100 Hz, 512 samples per frame, buffer capacity 4096 frames)

- C++: 0.48s
- Swift: 0.58s (1.208 slower)

20 000 000 cycles

- C++: 4.8s
- Swift: 6.3s (1.313 slower)

200 000 000 cycles

- C++: 47.43s
- Swift: 58.13s (1.226 slower)

Comment: You could make a C API for CARingBuffer which could then be called from Swift

Comment: Not a real solution, but can you use `CARingBuffer.h` provided by Apple and bridge it to Swift?

Comment: Thanks guys. But interested **pure** Swift implementation (without bridging). Not only for me, but for others.)

Comment: This is real-time high performance code. It is written in a mature language such as C++ for a reason, to be fast enough to provide audio data to your hardware timely. No memory allocating, deallocating, blocking or waiting should mix with critical real time audio code. Failing to understand this makes your program vulnerable to issues such as [priority inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion). I haven't come across any Swift code dealing with low-level real-time audio so far. Nor has Apple yet, AFAIK. I hope one day in the near future it will.

Comment: Most code of CARingBuffer performs **offset calculation** (integer arithmetic). CARingBuffer **allocates memory** one time during initialization (`CA_malloc`). 
Rest critical part of CARingBuffer code **performs memory operations** (`memset`, `memcpy`) in inline methods such as `StoreABL`, etc. I hope Swift compiler guess itself which methods to inline with `Whole Module Optimization` https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=27. We can use `memset`, `memcpy` in Swift as well. This make me thinking that Swift version of CARingBuffer can be as fast as C++. Correct me if I am wrong ;) Thanks!

Comment: I have very bad experience with whole module optimization - various mysterious linker problems which according to the error message where totally unrelated to whole module optimization. I found the reason by accident because whole module optimization was just turned on for the release build.

Comment: `CARingBuffer` is *not* a must. It is not even part of `CoreAudio` API, but of *PublicUtility*, which on one hand keeps backward compatibility with *QuickTime* for *Windows*, on the other hand gets updated rather irregularly. `CARingBuffer` used to be infamous in particular, for carrying some nasty bugs for quite a while. I had a few latency issues with it, which made be give up most of the API and go for simpler solutions. Perhaps you could invest in writing a Swift API for a high performance ring buffer?